US energy mix by state and year
How did each US state's electricity generation fuel shares (aka the energy mix) change over the years?
Here is the data for 2021 https://www.nei.org/resources/statistics/state-electricity-generation-fuel-shares
Using the waybackmachine, I've been able to get the same dataset for 2017 https://web.archive.org/web/20190208195739/https://www.nei.org/resources/statistics/state-electricity-generation-fuel-shares, and 2020 https://web.archive.org/web/20211115220028/https://www.nei.org/resources/statistics/state-electricity-generation-fuel-shares .
But I would hope that this type of data would exist much further back. Any hints for data in other years would be appreciated, even if it's just a one year.

https://www.eia.gov/electricity/data/state/generation_monthly.xlsx

Wow, this is great, thank you! It covers 2010-2024 (with 2023 and 2024 being preliminary).
